# Is it possible to use :bind (oracle style) in MYSQL query with Node?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am migrating the database of my node.js/typescript project from Oracle to MYSQL.
My queries/dml in Oracle are all bind in this style

```
conn.execute('select date, name from table
              where id = :ID and field = :VAR', 
             {ID: variable1, VAR: variable2});
```

When using MYSQL I found this:

```
connection.query('select date, name from table
                  where id = ? and field = ?',
                  [variable1, variable2]);
```

The second approach is worse for me because of following reasons:

i- I would to rewrite a lot of sql calls in my code

ii- I think the first approach is much more reliable, as you are not concerning of having unpredictable results due to changing in SQL

Although I found some mention to the first style [here](https://github.com/types/npm-mysql/blob/master/test/test.ts), it couldn't make it work

Any tips?

Comment: If you couldn't make it work, perhaps you should post why not.

Answer (score 0):

As I didn't find anything ready that could solve the issue, I tried to solve the problem. Maybe this could be helpful.

first, this code gets an Oracle bind interface type like `{ID: 105, DEPT: 'MKT'}` and a query like `'select * from emp where id = :ID and deptName = :DEPT'` and translates them to `[105,'MKT']` and `'select * from emp where id = ? and deptName = ?'`

here is the code

```
const endBindCharacters: string = ' )=';   
function prepareSQL(sql: string, binders: Object = null, valueArray: TBindArray): string {
    let ich: number = 0;
    let bindVariable: string;

    if (! binders) {
        if (sql.indexOf(':') > 0) {
            throw new CustomError(errorCodes.connection.sqlBoundWithNoBinders, 
                                  'No binders {} in a bound SQL ' + sql);
        };
        return sql;
    };

    while ((ich = sql.indexOf(':')) > 0) {
        bindVariable = '';
        while (!endBindCharacters.includes(sql[++ich]) && ich < sql.length) {
            bindVariable += sql[ich];
        };
        if (binders[bindVariable]) {
            valueArray.push(binders[bindVariable]);  
        } else {
            throw new CustomError(errorCodes.connection.bindVariableNotInBinders, ' Bind variable ' + bindVariable + 
                                  ' não encontradada no binders {} da expressão:\n' + sql)
        };
        sql = sql.replace(':' + bindVariable, ' ? ');
    };
    return sql;
};
```

This is the wrapper. It will get a Promise from the callback.

```
    export async function executeSQL (conn: TConnection, sql: string, 
binders: Object = {}): Promise<TReturn> {  
        let bindArray: TBindArray = [];
        sql = prepareSQL(sql, binders, bindArray);
        console.log(sql, binders, bindArray);
        return new Promise<TReturn>(function(resolve, reject) {
            conn.query(sql, bindArray , function(err: db.IError, results: TReturn) {
                if(err) {reject(err)}
                else {resolve(results)};
            });
        });
    };
```

Comment: What happens if I try to insert a string that contains a literal `:`? Or if I run an SQL statement with a comment that has a `:` in the comment? Or if I name my table or column with a `:` symbol (which is uncommon but technically allowed)?

Comment: There is no problem at all because this code is exactly to change the placeholders (binds) to the content of the variable. So the code 'where name = :nameVariable' will have the bind (nameVariable) replaced by the content of the variable, no matter if it has ':' or ')' inside it.

Comment: @BobJarvis this is a solution for the problem